# Show $X_n$ converges in probability to $0$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Suppose $X_1,X_2,...$ is a sequence of discrete random variables and $X_n$ has a probability function

$$p_n(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{n-1}{2n}  & \text{for } x=-1/n \text{ or } x=1/n\\
\frac1n  &\text{for }x=n \\
0 &\text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$

Show that $X_n$ converges in probability to $0$.

After using the formula I take it it becomes $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} p(|X_n-0|\geq \epsilon)=0$

But I’m not sure where to go from here

Comment: I edited your question; please take note of the LaTeX -- remember for next time. Also, note that I add a limit in front of your definition of convergence in probability, and the absolute values. Those are important so don't forget them!

Comment: Furthermore, I have gone through your old questions and you do not seem to accepted any answers or commented about them; please either accept/vote on the answers to your old questions or comment to address any further confusions. As it stands, we have no way of knowing if our answers are even being read or understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $\epsilon>0$ you choose, I can always find $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $\frac 1n < \epsilon$. This means that past that $N$, $X_n=\pm \frac 1n<\epsilon$ with probability $\frac{n-1}{2n}$. That means that only when $x=n$ (with probability $\frac 1n$) will $|X_n|$ be greater or equal to $\epsilon$, and thus $p(|X_n|\geq \epsilon)=\frac 1n$, which goes to $0$ as $n\to \infty$. This argument holds for all $\epsilon$, so $X_n\to_p 0$.

Comment: Amaxing thank you i was struggling to articulate the first few lines you put but now that makes much more sense.

Comment: Sorry about not accepting, I used this a while back loosely and didn’t respond, green tick Is accept yes?

Comment: @123123 correct, the green check mark is "accept" and basically means that the answer is correct and future people looking at the question should use the answer. Votes are just additional ways to say "good and useful answer".

Comment: side question would this also mean this is mean squared convergent to 0?

Comment: @123123 sorry, I haven't heard of that before.